# whats wrong in this $http request in angular?

Tags: angularjs, http, http-post

Here is the code :

```
(function () {

angular.module('PillApp').factory('AuthFactory',
    ['$q', '$timeout', '$http', 'Flash', '$state',
        function ($q, $timeout, $http, Flash, $state) {

            // create user variable
            var user = null;
            // return available functions for use in the controllers
            return ({
                isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
                getUserStatus: getUserStatus,
                login: login,
                logout: logout,
                register: register
            });

            function isLoggedIn() {
                if(user) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function getUserStatus(callback) {
                $http.get('/status/user')
                // handle success
                    .then(function (data) {
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        if(data.data !== ''){
                            user = true;
                            callback(user);
                        } else {
                            user = false;
                            callback(user);
                        }
                    });
            }

            function login(userProfile) {

                // create a new instance of deferred
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                console.log("Authentication Service - to send login to server");
                // send a post request to the server
                $http.post('/login',
                    userProfile)
                // handle success
                    .success(function (data, status) {
                        console.log("Authentication response received");
                        if(status == 200){
                            getUserStatus(function(result){
                                if(result){
                                    deferred.resolve();
                                    $state.go('A');
                                }else{
                                    deferred.reject();
                                    Flash.create('danger', "Ooops having issue logging in!", 0, {class: 'custom-class', id: 'custom-id'}, true);
                                    $state.go('A');
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            user = false;
                            Flash.clear();
                            Flash.create('danger', "Ooops having issue logging in!", 0, {class: 'custom-class', id: 'custom-id'}, true);
                            deferred.reject();
                        }
                    })
                    // handle error
                    .error(function (data) {
                        console.log("Authentication error - any flash messsage?");
                        user = false;
                        Flash.clear();
                        Flash.create('danger', "Ooops having issue logging in!", 0, {class: 'custom-class', id: 'custom-id'}, true);
                        deferred.reject();
                    });

                // return promise object
                return deferred.promise;
            }

            function logout() {

                // create a new instance of deferred
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                // send a get request to the server
                $http.get('/logout')
                // handle success
                    .success(function (data) {
                        user = false;
                        deferred.resolve();
                    })
                    // handle error
                    .error(function (data) {
                        user = false;
                        deferred.reject();
                    });

                // return promise object
                return deferred.promise;

            }

            function register(username, password) {

                // create a new instance of deferred
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                console.log("Sending registration to server");
                // send a post request to the server
                $http.post('/register',
                    {username: username, password: password})
                // handle success
                    .success(function (data, status) {
                        if(status){
                            console.log('Registration successful', data, status);
                            deferred.resolve();
                        } else {
                            console.log('Registration unsuccessful', data);
                            Flash.closeFlash();
                            Flash.create('danger', "Can't register with us!", 0, {class: 'custom-class', id: 'custom-id'}, true);
                            deferred.reject();
                        }
                    })
                    // handle error
                    .error(function (data) {
                        console.log('Registration error', data);
                        Flash.clear();
                        Flash.create('danger', "Ooops something went wrong!", 0, {class: 'custom-class', id: 'custom-id'}, true);
                        deferred.reject();
                    });

                // return promise object
                return deferred.promise;

            }

        }]);
})();
```

ERROR :

```
angular.js:14324 TypeError: $http.post(...).then is not a function
    at Object.login (http://ec2-52-77-252-229.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/services/auth.factory.js:55:22)
    at AppCtrl.vm.login (http://ec2-52-77-252-229.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/app.controller.js:35:25)
    at fn (eval at compile (http://ec2-52-77-252-229.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:236:285), <anonymous>:4:167)
    at e (http://ec2-52-77-252-229.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:281:195)
```

I tried $http.post().success also and it gives error like success is not defined

Than i tried $http.post().then also and it gives error like then is not defined

I have injected $http in a right way.it worked on localhost but during production it gives this kind of errors.

Comment: you need to show your **complete** controller definition here.  also, since `$http` returns a promise, wrapping that promise in a deferred is unnecessary.

Comment: @Claies  So i am using factory, and i have attached full code for it now

Answer (score 0):

You need to define functions containing http post directive in this manner :

```
 $scope.getUserCallback = function (callback) {
            $http.get('/status/user')
            // handle success
                .then(function (data) {
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    if(data.data !== ''){
                        user = true;
                        callback(user);
                    } else {
                        user = false;
                        callback(user);
                    }
                });
        };
```

then you can call it from inside the script wherever required as

```
$scope.getUserCallback();
```

and from an html element like this

```
 <my element ng-click="getUserCallback()"></my element>
```

Comment: That's not what i am looking for .

Comment: I think your code is correct , you need to check the urls ur using in get

Answer (score -1):

I think the `$http.post` call is failing due to `CORS`. You may need to enable `CORS` or send the appropriate `HTTP` headers in your request. The error you are getting because the `$http.post` is not returning the expected object which can execute the next `success` or `then` methods.

It would work correctly on your `localhost` as there is no `CORS` restriction in local development environment.

Comment: if `$http` is correctly injected into the controller, it ***always*** returns a promise, even if the promise itself failed to execute.  CORS wouldn't change what `$http` returns.